# File List extension give me a Typo3 Exception

Tags: typo3

File list extension throws the following Typo3 Exception:

> Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileReference::updateProperties()

when I selected the `file colection` view option. With `folder view` its all ok.

I  am using TYPO3 v8.7.7 an 2.2 extension version

Comment: You wrote about 2.2 extension version. Which extension do you mean? Is it working deactivating this extension?

Comment: Thank you,
the extension is file_list 2.2.2.
Yes the problem only happens when I use the extension with the option 'file collectio'

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug report more than a real question. According to the [official documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/file_list/Links.html),
 you would have been advised to create a ticket instead. This is just what I did for you: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82766

Please check the attached (linked) patch and report on the TYPO3 review platform if it solves the problem. Thanks.